# Using Visual Studio, is it possible to break lines in web.sitemap?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web.sitemap

**Using Visual Studio, is it possible to break lines in web.sitemap?**

Most of my web.sitemap roles have many items, and I often have to make adjustments for various reasons.  While I have been able to turn on "word wrap" it is still difficult to scan at times.

To give you a better idea of what I mean, here is a copy of what I often work with.  It's the comma-delimited list inside the quotes of the roles attribute I'd like to be able to break by hard returns so that I can more easily scan it.

*So instead of this,*

```
<siteMapNode title="1B" roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum,ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,ROSE\DM_CRA_Principal,ROSE\DM_CRA_Teacher,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Director,ROSE\DM_RMG_SPED_Specialist,ROSE\DM_RMG_SS_Clerk,ROSE\DM_RMG_SS_Manager"
url="http://wales:4886/CRA_Goals/MIA_1b.aspx">
```

*I would like to be able to do this (somehow).*  I have tried the obvious, like actually doing a hard return after each comma, I got a server error.  I did a web search for this literal topic and could find none.  Am I missing something really obvious, or is this not possible for an asp.net website?

Thank you for any insight.

```
<siteMapNode 
   title="1B" 
   roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager,
          ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum, 
          ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS,
          [and so on]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I didn't find any answer online because I was being too specific in my choice of question.  What I should have asked was "How can I continue a string to the next line?"

If I add " _" to the end of each line (except for the final line of the string), I don't cause any debug errors.

```
<siteMapNode 
title="1B" 
roles="ROSE\DM_RMG_Data_Manager _,
ROSE\DM_RMG_Curriculum _, 
ROSE\DM_RMG_OoS _,
[and so on]
```